# Scheme : What's error in my tail-recursion code?

Tags: scheme

```
(define log2_tail
   (lambda (n)
     (letrec ((log2 (lambda (n res)
                       (if (= n 1)
                           res
                           (log2 (quotient (+ n 1) 2) (+ 1 res))))))
        (log2 n 0))))
(log2_tail 3)
```

Above code is scheme tail-recursion code to compute the integer part of log base 2.(Actually I'm not sure) But if I execute with argument 3, the result is 2 not 1. I guess it's because I use letrec, then how can i resolve it?

Comment: Don't add 1 when calculating the quotient.

Comment: @Terje D. Oops I don't think about modify that part, thanks. Then I wonder it's tail-recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a clearer way to write this is with 'named let'; which might allow one to focus more readily on the functionality.  Like this.

```
(define (log2_tail n)
  (let log2 ((n n) (res 0))
    (if (= n 1)
        res
        (log2 (quotient n 2)
              (+ 1 res)))))
```

A 'named let' is translated into a `letrec` by the compiler.

Comment: I +1'd your post because it's correct, but one minor nit-pick: it's named `let`, not `named let`. (Look at the R5RS document, for example, and you'll see it's typeset the same way.)

Comment: Thanks I'm not used to other form. Then it's right tail-recursion?

Comment: It is tail recursive because the recursive call to `log2` is in the tail position of `if` and `if` is in the tail position of `let`.